# Загрузка картинки ajax js

Tags: javascript, ajax, drag-n-drop

Делаю загрузку картинки с помощью Drag&Drop. Тоесть кнопка "submit" не предусматривается.

D&D-легко, Интересует только:
1) как взять картинку из input[file]
2) отправить с помощью ajax не перезагружая страницу

Большое спасибо!
P.S. желательно без jquery, не хочу подгружать целую библиотеку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я реализую это таким образом:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('Your ID input file');
var file_ = input.files[0];
if (file_) {
  upload_file(file_);
}

function upload_file(file) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var form = new FormData();
    var url;
    
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(event) {}
    
    xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = function() {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            console.log('success');
        } else {
            console.log('error ' + this.status);
        }
    }
    
    url = '/index.php?act=upload&a=newPhoto';
    
    form.append('photo', file);
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.send(form);
}
```

Comment: О, оно! работает!)) то что нужно!)